# R data from sf package is missing data from small island states

Tags: r, r-sf

I am creating a map with R that should include all SADC economies. This map should be coloured in a later step according to an additional data set that I want to merge with the map. At the moment I have been using the **sf package** to map the SADC economies.

These include the **following 16 Member States:** Angola, Botswana, Comoros, Democratic Republic of Congo, Eswatini, Lesotho, Madagascar, Malawi, Mauritius, Mozambique, Namibia, Seychelles, South Africa, United Republic Tanzania, Zambia and Zimbabwe.

While selecting the countries for my map, I could not find data for the three island states: **Comoros, Mauritius & Seychelles**

- Is there any opportunity to **manually add the geom (MULTIPOLYGON) data **and if so, where do I find the information?
- Alternatively: is there an **alternative package, which includes all SADC country coordinates** with which I could plot the map?

I have not found the missing data in the iso_a2 column (containing all iso2 codes) in the name_long column (containing all names), or when filtering for all countries on the continent Africa in the continent column

Here is my sample code

```
# install packages
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf) # for geographic data # classes and functions for vector data

# show African countries
Africa <- world %>%
  filter(continent == "Africa")
View(Africa) # find all SADC economies with the right name
# problem: missing:  Comoros, Mauritius & Seychelles

# create SADC vector according to country names in dataset
SADCvector2 <- SADCvector <- c("Angola","Botswana", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "eSwatini", "Lesotho", "Madagascar", "Malawi",
 "Mozambique","Namibia", "Seychelles", "South Africa", "Tanzania","Zambia", "Zimbabwe")
                               
# select SADC countries
SADC1 <- world %>%
  filter(name_long %in% SADCvector2) %>%
  #select only variables of interest
  select(name_long, geom)

plot(SADC1)
```

Comment: The `rnaturalearth` package should contain sf files for all the countries you want.

Comment: You might find better answers on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: where does your `world` object come from? I don't think it lives in any of the libraries listed...  In any case I suggest using `giscoR::gisco_get_countries(region = "Africa")` instead; I checked and Comoros, Mauritius and Seychelles are in.